# Angular 4, angular-in-memory-web-api, and Observables: createDb() returning Observable or Promise does not work

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, in-memory-database

I have been beating against this problem for a couple days now and cannot move forward.

I am trying to mock a database using some source JSON files that represent tables with foreign key relationships.  Let us say that there is an entity `A` and an entity `B`, where `A` has a many-to-one relationship with `B`.  In addition to requiring some additional cleanup, the JSON files only list primary keys for these relationships, so I have DTO wrappers `RawA` and `RawB` that I can map to `A` and `B` respectively once I get the data.

I am using the angular-in-memory-web-api, so I have set up my app.module.ts to use a custom service that allows me to retrieve the JSON files like so:

```
HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
  InMemoryDataService,
  { apiBase: '/api', dataEncapsulation: false, passThruUnknownUrl: true }
)
```

In my app.component.ts, I temporarily have an `ngOnInit()` method that test the construction of this database:

```
ngOnInit() {
  let result = this.http.get('/api/A')
    .subscribe(
      next => { console.log('next:'); console.log(next); },
      error => { console.log('error:'); console.log(error); },
      () => console.log('complete')
    );
}
```

As I understand this, the in-memory database should see this request, call `createDb()` on my service, and subscribe to the Observable that my method returns, and then use the list of `A`s I create in `subscribe()`.

I cannot get this to work.  I have tried many things, perhaps the most intuitive of which is:

```
// most imports omitted, but I am using
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService() {
  private static aUrl = './assets/data/a.json';
  private static bUrl = './assets/data/b.json';

  private http: HttpClient;

  constructor( private injector: Injector ) {}

  createDb( reqInfo?: RequestInfo ): {} | Observable<{}> | Promise<{}> {
    this.http = this.injector.get(HttpClient);

    return Observable.forkJoin(
        this.http.get<RawA[]>(InMemoryDataService.aUrl),
        this.http.get<RawB[]>(InMemoryDataService.bUrl)
      ).map(
        result => {
          let bs = (result[1] as RawB[]).map(raw => new B(raw));
          let as = (result[0] as RawA[]).map(raw => new A(raw, bs));
          return { A: as, B: bs };
        }
      );
  }
}
```

The `subscribe()` callbacks in `ngOnInit()` never run.  I have tried various combinations of mapping, subscribing, converting to Promises, and swearing, and I cannot anything better than either `ngOnInit()` never doing anything or prompting the in-memory DB to return a 404.

I know that the `forkJoin()` documentation warns that all the Observables need to return before it will produce any values, but as best I can tell, the two `http.get()` calls should return if the wrapping plumbing subscribes to them.  The following code successfully logs the database I expect (but it generates a 404, probably because the immediate call to api/A sees an empty array):

```
  createDb( reqInfo?: RequestInfo ): {} | Observable<{}> | Promise<{}> {
    this.http = this.injector.get(HttpClient);

    let database: { A: A[], B: B[] } = { A: [], B: [] };
    Observable.forkJoin(
        this.http.get<RawA[]>(InMemoryDataService.aUrl),
        this.http.get<RawB[]>(InMemoryDataService.bUrl)
      ).subscribe(
        result => {
          database.B = (result[1] as RawB[]).map(raw => new B(raw));
          database.A = (result[0] as RawA[]).map(raw => new A(raw, database.B));
          console.log(database);
          return database;
        }
      );
    return database;
  }
  // console logs {A: Array(100), B: Array(20)}, and inspection shows the field values are all correct
```

What am I missing to make this work?  Also, is this legitimately tricky, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### CreateDb

Looking at your code:

```typescript
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get<RawA[]>(InMemoryDataService.aUrl),
    this.http.get<RawB[]>(InMemoryDataService.bUrl)
  ).subscribe(
```

I suspect that since you hooked up all http requests and haven't create Db yet these requests will be always in status waiting.

In order to overcome it i would use something else to get json data.

For instance [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```typescript
createDb( reqInfo?: RequestInfo ): Observable<{}> | Promise<{}> {
  this.http = this.injector.get(HttpClient);

  return Promise.all([
      fetch(InMemoryDataService.aUrl),
      fetch(InMemoryDataService.bUrl)
    ])
    .then((result: any) => {
      return Promise.all(result.map(x => x.json()));
    })
    .then(
      result => {
        const bs = (result[1] as RawB[]).map(raw => new B(raw));
        const as = (result[0] as RawA[]).map(raw => new A(raw, bs));
        return { A: as, B: bs };
      }
    );
}
```

### ApiBase

Another thing you need to change is api url

**app.module.ts**

```typescript
{ apiBase: 'api/', dataEncapsulation: false, passThruUnknownUrl: true }
           ^^^^^^
```

**component.ts**

```typescript
let result = this.http.get('api/A')
                           ^^^^^^^^^
```

Or you can use the following pair:

```typescript
{ apiBase: '/', dataEncapsulation: false, passThruUnknownUrl: true }

let result = this.http.get('/A')
```

The reason of this is how `angular-in-web-memory-api` [parses your url](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/748891871fdb61d071f9dbf57fa8174924cebfb7/src/in-mem/backend.service.ts#L519-L569)

Comment: A slight rewrite of your `createdDb()` method and removing that incorrect slash in the URL worked perfectly.  Thank you so much!  +1, and the bounty when SO lets me award it.